# I want to change keyboard input language programmatically using php

Tags: php, keyboard

I want to change keyboard input language programmatically using PHP.

my website is fully multi language supportive by user choice selection so everything is fine, but user entered something at that time i want to change keyboard language same as page content changed.

It's not possible because it is a client side and it's related to operating system.

now i have a one solution and that is create a custom keyboard i.e "**virtual keyboard**" but i'm not sure because i think it's a software so, i think user need to install it manualy.

I want programmatically solution.

please help me.

Comment: 85%? Where does this number come from?

Comment: You are correct, this is something php cannot do.

Comment: @Masiorama maybe from a hat, near the rabbit.

Comment: @mukund-sojitra - link

Answer (score 3):

It can be possible with virtual keyboard
[demo](http://allanguages.info/#layouts=)